# Vinyl Plank Floors Lifting - what to do?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

Can anyone give me some advice on this? Just moved into a new home in a humid area (FL) and we didn't notice this before but the LVP floors are peaking/separating on the 1st floor in some areas. It's not so horrible, but on further investigation I don't know if the previous installers left an expansion gap or placed a vapor barrier. The subfloor is concrete. I ran a dehumidifier for a bit but no change after going from humidity in 40s to 30s. It's not an issue on the second floor.

Here are some photos: https://imgur.com/a/FKQ3U5y

Should I worry about this? I think my options are to leave it as is, redo the same floor with a vapor barrier, or change the first floor for tile.
Appreciate all advice, thank you!

Comment: Can you push down on the raised up sections, or are they solidly raised?  That might help to identify if they can be flattened or not, and would help indicate if they truly are LVP or if it's laminate.

Comment: They are in fact laminate. There was no vapor barrier installed previously but the laminate advertises that it comes with its own underlayment padding. Because the issue is only in a few areas near doors, could I get away with redoing only those areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen LVP do that .

I'm thinking you have Laminate flooring. The materials used and construction of LVP will not lend itself to peaking, but laminate definitely will when it is subject to moisture.

If the flooring is laminate, unfortunately there is nothing you can do but replace it.

I have installed LVP on an outside lanai. It gets rain blown on it and the occasional stray sprinkler.  It  shows no effect.

Comment: You are correct they are laminate. If there is no vapor barrier how important is it that it covers the entire floor vs just the affected areas?

Comment: @drwoof,  If the subfloor is concrete, I would put vapor barrier even if the manufacturer said it wasn't needed.  The question is do you want to remove all the flooring, or just replace what is ruined?  Personally I would try to get vapor barrier under what needs replaced and hope for the best.  If more failed, I would replace it all with LVP

Answer (score 0):

Since we can't quite see other areas of the floor, if the bowing is just at the entry door it has gotten more moisture on it. Likely it's from drips after rain when entering the house which caused the planks to swell. You can try to find a box of replacement flooring and pull out the warped flooring to swap those out. In the future just be careful, a rubber-backed jute mat outside and a small rubber-backed carpet inside to wick off moisture from shoes is advisable, and maybe even when removing shoes at your door into a rubber shoe tray just inside the door, a shoe bench might take help.